# Designing a REST API

Tags: api, rest, url, uri, api-design

In my application, I will have clients trying to book some slots. For this, the client will give some input and based on that input, I have to first create these slots and then return them to the client. Then after getting the slots, the user will book one of these slots. This "book" action is not creating any new resource but simply modifying 2 existing resources.

How do I design my URIs and what methods should I use?

EDIT:

I have 1 existing resource whose URI is: /api/v1/vehicle/id

Using the application front-end a user will fill some form data, with fields `date` and `booking-type` and submit it. Then this data will be used by the backend to "calculate" (no resource called `slots` exists currently) booking slots available to the user. These calculated `slots` will then be saved in the DB and returned as a response to the user. Out of these slots, the user will `book` a slot. However, this `book` action will not create any new resource, instead it will simply modify an existing `vehicle` resource (add booking related data to it) and the slots object returned by the previous request. I want to create a REST API for this.

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
POST /api/v1/slot                    (1)
PUT/PATCH /api/v1/vehicle/id            (2)
PUT/PATCH /api/v1/slot/id            (3)
```

First, I am not sure if I should use `PUT` or `PATCH` here, in both (2) and (3). I will only be supplying partial updates to the request. Second, when the user selects a slot and clicks on `book` button, the front end can only send 1 request to the server. But here, I need to modify 2 resources. How do I do this? I guess I should create 1 URI like /api/v1/createbooking and use the POST method. Then in my backend call 2 different methods to update `vehicle` and `slot` objects. Is this URI structure and naming good?

Comment: You have to provide some more details.  It is very hard to suggest anything by anyone at the moment :)

Comment: @SriHans Added details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I design my URIs and what methods should I use?

How would you do it with web pages?

It sounds like you would have the user navigate to a form which collects the date, booking type, etc.  The user submits the form, and the information is sent to the server; because this is not an essentially read-only operation, we'd expect the form to indicate that the POST method should be used.

The server would make its local changes, and present to the user a new form, with the input controls presenting the available options.  Once again, choosing a slot doesn't seem to have read-only semantics (we're passing information to the server), so we would see POST again.

What are the URI targets?  One way to choose which resources should handle the POST requests is to consider the implications of [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4); because caches know to invalidate the target-uri of a successful POST request, it can be useful to target a resource that is likely to change when the request is successful.

My guess would be that first post would go to the resource that presents the slot choices (since what we are doing is generating new choices for the customer).

For the second submission, since the representation of the vehicle is what is going to be changed by selecting a slot, it makes sense to send that POST request to the vehicle uri.

In general, think about how you read (GET) the changing information from the server; you change that information by sending some request to the same URI.

---

> I am not sure if I should use PUT or PATCH here

PUT and PATCH are typically available together, not as distinct things.  They are two different methods for sending a replacement representation of a resource.

A simple example: if you wanted to change the title of `/home.html`, you could either PUT the entire HTML document with the new title, or you could PATCH the HTML document by sending a patch-document in some format that the server understands.

In other words, both of these methods have *remote authoring* semantics; we normally would choose between them based on considerations unrelated to your domain model (if the document is small relative to the size of the HTTP headers, a client would usually choose PUT for the additional idempotent semantic guarantees.  If the document is really big, but the change is small, we might prefer PATCH).

---

> I need to modify 2 resources.

There's no rule that says a request may only modify one resource.  The side effects of  the changes may impact the representations of several resources (see [4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) and [4.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) of RFC 7231).

What's tricky is telling general purpose clients (and intermediate components) which cached representations are invalidated by the change.  Out of the box, we only have semantics for the effective request uri, the Location and the Content-Location.  Location and Content-Location already mean something, so you can't just hijack them without the potential of introducing a big mess).

You could do it with [Linked Cache Invalidation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-linked-cache-inv-04), using "well known" link relations to identify other documents that have been changed by the request.  Unfortunately, LCI doesn't seem to have achieved the status of a "standard", so we may be out of luck for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer, its very very helpful. I have a few more questions though. 

"LCI doesn't seem to have achieved the status of a "standard", so we may be out of luck for the time being"

So in my situation, if I dont handle this, the clients can return the old response from cache instead of making a fresh request?